# Working issue in software development

Tags: communication, work-environment, startup

I have a friend asking about his software career with his current employer.

The company is very small; developer, 2 contractors and 2 full staff (including CTO). My friend isn't a highly paid contractor. It's really underpaid  but he wants to gain some experience. He personally lacks confidence.

Currently the staff are working hard out and very late but my friend was worn out by the long hours.

His problem was he found it hard to follow their context. They gave him a Task but no guidance of what it should be. Also the database was not fully explained to my friend, especially when dealing with business logic, and there is no interface layout etc. He can code but lacks knowledge of the underlying business logic.

Are all software companies like this?

Comment: Are all software company are like this? No

Answer (score 1):

No, they're not. A good company will invest the time to ensure you know what to do and how to do it, in order to get the most from it's employees.

There are several warnings here that show that this company is struggling (no growth, long hours, low pay) and I assume at least some of the reason for that is the problems you've listed. Apply for a new job with a company that is growing and can afford to pay the market rate, because they've probably got better processes and management.